# How to remove fade from gradient in css

Tags: css

I have got following button in my html code
`<input type="button" id="button" title="button" name="button" class="button" value="button" />`
and this css attached

```
.button{
  width:200px;
  height:;50px;
  position:relative;
  top:50px;
  left:200px;
  background:-webkit-linear-gradient(180deg,white 33%,blue 67%)
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mudkcuqj/

Now my spirit desires to remove that heinous fade which is caused by `gradient`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you're looking to remove the fade from blue to white, and have it be blue up until a point, then change to white, have the colors start and end at the same point.

```css
.button{
  width:200px;
  height:50px;
  position:relative;
  top:50px;
  left:200px;
  background:linear-gradient(180deg,white 33%,blue 33%);
  background:-webkit-linear-gradient(180deg,white 33%,blue 33%);
}
```

```html
<input type="button" id="button" title="button" name="button" class="button" value="button" />
```

Comment: Thanks dawg,this works perfectly,faultlessly, superbly, superlatively, excellently, flawlessly, to perfection, without fault, ideally, inimitably, incomparably, impeccably, immaculately, exquisitely, consummately,

Comment: @user7302801 you're welcome, de nada, don't mention it, my pleasure, no problem, not at all, no worries, think nothing of it, you bet.

Comment: this works for all browsers except Safari for me. Where it then repeats itself. To avoid repeating I then add background-attachment: fixed, but then the start/stop colours no longer works. any ideas?

Comment: @Kirsten it looks ok to me in safari, though I did just notice the background declaration wasn't working at all due to a missing semicolon from an edit on 10/21. Can you check again with the updated code? And if you still see it - what version of safari?

Comment: On Firefox adding the -webkit- prefix actually works differently with the degrees. If I have 90deg for "linear-gradient" I need to use 0deg for "-webkit-linear-gradient" to match the same direction

Answer (score 3):

Just add "blue 0.1%" between "white 33%" and "blue 67%"

```
.button{
  width:200px;
  height:50px;
  position:relative;
  top:50px;
  left:200px;
  background:linear-gradient(180deg,white 33%,blue 0.1%,blue 67%);
}
```

Comment: works perfectly, and to point out, the last two colors HAVE to be the same